# How do I set a cell to be a number but to also have mg after?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to record the weight of a few items in milligrams, and I want it to be that I just type in a number in a cell and then it has the number but adds mg afterwards.

I get the feeling I may be able to do this with custom number formats and I have tried, but it seems to change the number and mess everything up.

Surely there's an easy way?

I've tried going to custom number formats.

I was expecting to type into a cell 30 and it come up as 30mg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Custom number format` option in the menu. To get to it, you go to `Format` (in the top menu bar) -> `Number` -> `Custom number format`.

An example of what you're looking for is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AM8v_rTZ7xf1sOE9a5Zcm5IOR_hB_302EBW6GQPXfYk/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: yes i that example is what i need, but i tried going to custom number format and it changed my number from 30 to like 5 or something. what do i have to do when i go to the custom number format section? maybe i'm going something wrong there

Comment: In this case, you don't need to do anything, because I did it for you. But in general, to add `hello world` to the end of a number (e.g. `42 hello world`), you go to the Custom number format section and input `0" hello world"`

Comment: Details of other things can be found here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?visit_id=638239531244046677-2048392319&p=drive_custom_numbers&rd=1#zippy=%2Ccustom-number-formatting

Comment: Obviously there's a lot of flexibility so every possibility can't be detailed here